# iOS CI: How to run calabash tests using bots?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, bots, calabash, osx-server

I am using Calabash to perform UI tests in my iOS app.

Calabash is chosen because tests could be written using Gherkin-style and I can use RubyMine.

Good things: any time during writing gherkin scenarios I can easily get a list of already implemented functions (like: When user successfully logged in) and also RubyMine will create functions for every new scenario. These are actually huge benefits.

Bad things: In addition to UI tests in Calabash I also have native unit tests which I run using bots, but I didn't figure out how run Calabash tests using bots on OS X Server.

So in ideal world I would like to have something what KIF does: bots could run UI tests and give nice OS X Server web page results, but at the same time I'd like to have all benefits of using Calabash + RubyMine

Or maybe there is a way to run calabash cucumber tests on OS X Server using bots? And I am not really comfortable using OS X Server for native unit tests and Jenkins for cucumber tests. I just want one tool do whole thing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new bot and set its Schmeme to your Calabash scheme, e.g., `MyXcodeScheme-cal`. Then  for example add an iPhone in the testing tab as target.

But unfortunately a successful integration does not mean that the Calabash tests has passed - only that the test were executed! So the Calabash test results itself has to be investigated manually afterwards :S

:)